# Geospatial PDF with GlobalMapper

Tags: geospatial-pdf, global-mapper

I've generated a Geospatial PDF with GDAL 1.11.3 library.

When I open it with Global Mapper v18, it looks upside down and it's not well georeferenced.

I've opened it with QGIS and with Acrobat Reader, and it seems it's ok.

So I don't know if it's a bug, my file is wrong or Geospatial PDF is not supported.

This is my file [geomapa.pdf](http://cd8ba0b44a15c10065fd-24461f391e20b7336331d5789078af53.r23.cf1.rackcdn.com/gmf.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/88/5aef3cecf894ff27235af6466bb1db.pdf)

Comment: Obviously different implementations in Global Mapper vs. GDAL and Acrobat Reader about reading georeference. Almost impossible to say anything more without having a test image and Global Mapper. What does your Global matter report about the properties of the image?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a bug.

I've sent it to the Global Mapper's support team.

Comment: Could you add more information about why it looks like a bug.